# How do I specify that I want an "Added In Order" linear regression in R?

Tags: r, regression

I want to consider the possible predictors in the following sequential order: x2, x3, and x1. In SAS, this test is called a "Type I" test.

I currently have my code as:

```
model <- lm(logvl ~ x2 + x3 + x1 + x2:x3 + x2:x1)
anova(model)
```

But when I calculate the F-statistics by hand, they do not match with the F-statistics that the ANOVA table is producing.

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: logvl
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)   
x2         1  0.161  0.1607  0.2655 0.608080   
x3         1  5.694  5.6938  9.4055 0.003135 **
x1         1  3.985  3.9854  6.5834 0.012572 * 
x2:x3      1  0.029  0.0290  0.0479 0.827372   
x2:x1      1  0.518  0.5177  0.8552 0.358446   
Residuals  66 39.954  0.6054                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The formula that I am using for the partial F-statistics is:

> (SSR of full model - SSR of reduced model) / (MSE of the full model)

edit:

Solution:

```
m0 <- lm(y ~ 1)
m1 <- lm(y ~ x2)
m2 <- lm(y ~ x2 + x3)
m3 <- lm(y ~ x2 + x3 + x1)

anova(m0)
anova(m1)
anova(m1, m2)
anova(m1, m2, m3)
```

Comment: What are the values that you calculated by hand that you are expecting?

Comment: Edited the post to include what I'm expecting

Comment: If I read your writing correctly, your denominator is wrong, it should be MSE of residuals and should the same for all the F statistic calculated, which is 0.6054.

Comment: There are many formulations for it, for example RSS2 / degree of freedom of residuals, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test, but the denominator is always the unexplained variance of the full model.

Comment: @StupidWolf In this case, the MSE's are different for each F-statistic because the full models for each sequential regression are different.